# JQuery UI Dialog button enable and disable doesn't work on first opening, but does on subsequent openings

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I have text input field that will disable the "Set" button if the number entered is not between 45 and 105. When the dialog box is first opened, the button disable does not work, but when closed and reopened, it works all subsequent times. I am stumped. Any help would definitely be appreciated.

```
            $("#dialog-2").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Set": function(){
                    $("#NumberEntry").on("input", function(){
                        if(errorCheck === false){
                            $(".ui-dialog-buttonpane button:contains('Set')").button("enable");                             
                        }
                        else {
                            $(".ui-dialog-buttonpane button:contains('Set')").button("disable");    
                        }
                    });
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                },
                Cancel: function(){
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: what is `errorCheck`? is it a variable? please share that code also.

Comment: try to wrap this code jquery document.ready function

Comment: I think initial value of `errorCheck` is always `true` and hence it is making button disabled. and from second time this values coming as `false`.

Comment: errorCheck is function that checks the number entered and returns false if in-range and true if out-of-range. I will try to post code later.
The code is wrapped in a jquery document.ready.

Comment: It dynamically enables/disables the "Set" button as values are typed into the text box. It works perfectly after it has been opened and closed once. It's just the first time that it fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the problem now. I had the button disable code block within the button itself, so that it didn't execute until I pressed the button, which is why it worked when the dialog box was re-opened (I was closing it with the "Set" button). I moved the code outside of the button and it works now. Thanks for your comments and time!